# IBM Content Navigator ContentList clickable column

Tags: ibm-content-navigator

I'm able to render the ContentList within ICN. I have a requirement wherein I need to make the first column of the grid as clickable. In normal dojo, we use a formatter function to do this. Is there any way to do in ICN?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I had to change from ContentList to gridx. This way I formatted the column to be a clickable.

Regards,
Manju